# Find entity with most relations filtered by criteria

Tags: sql, prisma

```
model Player {
  id   String @id
  name String @unique
  game Game[]
}

model Game {
  id       String   @id
  isWin    Boolean
  playerId String
  player   Player   @relation(fields: [playerId], references: [id])
}
```

I would like to find a player with most wins. How would I do that with `prisma`? If there is no prisma "native" way to do it, what is the most efficient way to do this with raw SQL?

The best I could think of is:

```js
    prisma.player.findMany({
      include: {
        game: {
          where: {
            isWin: true,
          },
        },
      },
    })
```

But it has huge downside that you need to filter and order results in Node manually, and also store all results in memory while doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `groupBy` API you can find the player with the most wins using two queries.

##### 1. Activate orderByAggregateGroup

You'l need to use the `orderByAggregateGroup` preview feature and use Prisma version `2.21.0` or later.

Update your Prisma Schema as follows

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["orderByAggregateGroup"]  
}
// ... rest of schema
```

##### 2. Find playerId of most winning player

Use a `groupBy` query to do the following:

1. Group games by the `playerId` field.
2. Find the count of `game` records where `isWin` is true.
3. Order them in descending order by the count mentioned in 2.
4. Take only 1 result (since we want the player with the most wins. You can change this to get the first-n players as well).

The combined query looks like this:

```js
 const groupByResult = await prisma.game.groupBy({
        by: ["playerId"],
        where: {
            isWin: true,
        },
        _count: {
            isWin: true,
        },
        orderBy: {
            _count: {
                isWin: "desc",
            },
        },
        take: 1,   // change to "n" you want to find the first-n most winning players. 
    });

    const mostWinningPlayerId = groupByResult[0].playerId;
```

I would suggest checking out the Group By section of the [Aggregation, grouping, and summarizing article](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/aggregation-grouping-summarizing#group-by) in the prisma docs, which explains how group by works and how to use it with filtering and ordering.

#### 3. Query player data with findUnique

You can trivially find the player using a `findUnique` query as you have the `id`.

```js
const mostWinningPlayer = await prisma.player.findUnique({
        where: {
            id: mostWinningPlayerId,
        },
    });
```

Optionally, if you want the first "n" most winning players, just put the appropriate number in the `take` condition of the first `groupBy` query. Then you can do a `findMany` with the [in operator](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#in) to get all the player records. If you're not sure how to do this, feel free to ask and I'll clarify with sample code.

Comment: Actually tried this approach with `groupBy` too, but did't know about `orderByAggregateGroup` flag, thank you! I was hoping for one query solution, but this will work for now, I guess.

Comment: Welcome! I don't think a single query solution is supported at the moment. You can [order by the count of related records](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting#sort-by-relation-aggregate-value-preview), but can't add conditional counts such as, when ```isWin: true```.