# Find entities sorted by aggregated property of their relations

Tags: sql, prisma

Question is quite similar to [Find entity with most relations filtered by criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68546572/find-entity-with-most-relations-filtered-by-criteria), but slightly different.

```
model Player {
  id   String @id
  name String @unique
  game Game[]
}

model Game {
  id       String   @id
  isWin    Boolean
  playerId String
  player   Player   @relation(fields: [playerId], references: [id])
}
```

I would like to find 10 players with best win rate (games with `isWin=true` divided by total amount of games by that player).

Direct and slow way to do that is to find all the players who won at least once and count their wins (first query). Then for each of them count their total amount of games (second query). Then do the math and sorting on the application side while holding results in memory.

Is there simpler way to do that? How would I do that with `prisma`? If there is no prisma "native" way to do it, what is the most efficient way to do this with raw SQL?

Answer (score 0):

This is simple aggregation:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN isWin THEN 1 END) AS wins
     , COUNT(g.playerId) AS played
     , 100 * COUNT(CASE WHEN isWin THEN 1 END)
           / COUNT(g.playerId) AS rate
  FROM player AS p
  JOIN game   AS g
    ON g.playerId = p.id
 GROUP BY p.name         -- since p.name is unique, not the id.
 ORDER BY rate DESC
 LIMIT 10
;
```

Adjust as needed for your database.  I adjusted in case the join becomes a LEFT JOIN, to handle players with no games played.

Executable example with PG, as indicated by the comments below.
[Working test case - no data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f9e11b569d4a8c5203625169d535679d)

Comment: That gives me an error relation "player" does not exist. Would providing more info about my tables help? Like how they look in raw sql or something

Comment: Adjust the names of the tables based on your database requirements.  Some identifiers will be case sensitive or require quoting in certain databases. For instance, for your database Player might not be the same as player and "Player" might be different than Player (without quotes).

Comment: I am using Postgres, tried different way, still have an error. Also, `wins` and `played` are unused in your answer, is that intentionally or is it a typo?

Comment: Could you show your postgresql test case in an executable form?  See: dbfiddle.uk for a simple way to show your test case.  Here's the initial test case with the SQL I showed above.  Adjust this test case as needed to show your problem: ```https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f9e11b569d4a8c5203625169d535679d```

Comment: Yes.  The unused derived columns are just to show the sub-expressions used in the rate calculation.